# Add const to reference

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I want to add const to a reference type by `typedef const A B;`.

Somehow it doesn't work. Is this not possible in c++?

Test:

```
#include <type_traits>
typedef int& A;
typedef const A B;  // <-- Add const
// typedef std::add_const<A>::type B;  // also doesn't work.
static_assert(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<
        B>::type>::value, "is const");
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
add2.cpp:5:1: error: static assertion failed: is const
 static_assert(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Somehow it doesn't work. Is this not possible in c++?

Not with the way you are doing it. `typedef` does not work like pre-processor macros.

```
typedef int& A;
typedef const A B;
```

does not translate to

```
typedef int& A;
typedef const int& B;
```

The `const` in

```
typedef const A B;
```

applies to `A`, not the `int` part of `A`. Since references are immutable in C++, `const A` is the same as `A` from a type point view.

---

You can use:

```
typedef int const& B;
```

If you want to derive it from `A`, you an use:

```
using B = typename std::remove_reference<A>::type const&;
```

If you are able to use C++14 or a later version, you can simplify that to:

```
using B = std::remove_reference_t<A> const&;
```

Comment: West const loses again.

Comment: @Yakk, this is the first time I am hearing of that expression. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `std::add_const<T>` doesn't do what you think for references.
The way to add `const` to a reference is this:

```
    using in_type = double&;

    using out_type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<in_type>>>;

    static_assert( std::is_same<out_type, double const&>{} , "!");
```

---

I got bitten by this again and found my own answer a year later.
Even wanted to vote it up :).

This is a bit more general and more concise, but still not perfect.

```
    using in_type = Ref;

    using out_type = decltype( std::as_const(std::declval<in_type>()));
```