# `const T` with T = char* is not `const char*`?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constants, typedef

I have a generic linked list:

```
template <class E>
class linked_element {
    linked_element<E> *last = nullptr, *next = nullptr;
    const E elem;
public:
    explicit linked_element(const E elem) : elem(elem) { }
    linked_element(const linked_element& cpy) : next(cpy.next), last(cpy.last), elem(cpy.elem) { }
    ~linked_element() {
        if(next != nullptr) next->last = last;
        if(last != nullptr) last->next = next;
    }
    linked_element& operator =(linked_element& other) {
        if(this != &other) {
            last = other.last;
            next = other.next;
            elem = other.elem;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void add(linked_element<E> *next) {
        next->last = this;
        this->next = next;
    }

    const E& get() {
        return elem;
    }

    linked_element<E> *getLast() {
        return last;
    }

private:
    linked_element() = default;
};

template <class T>
class linked_list {
    linked_element<T*> *end = nullptr;
    std::size_t size = 0;
public:
    linked_list() = default;

    void push(const T& elem) {
        auto e = new linked_element<T*>(&elem);
        if(end != nullptr) end->add(e);
        end = e;
        size++;
    }

    T& peek() {
        checkAndCrash();
        return *(end->get());
    }

    void pop() {
        checkAndCrash();
        auto tmp = end->getLast();
        delete end;
        end = tmp;
        size--;
    }

    bool empty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    void checkAndCrash() {
        //...
    }
};
```

But when I try to use it with char as such:

```
int main() {
    using std::string;

    string a("a"), b("b"), c("c");

    linked_list<char> list;

    list.push('a');
    list.push('b');
    list.push('c');

    while (!list.empty()) {
        std::cout << list.peek() << std::endl;
        list.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
In file included from .../linked_list/main.cpp:3:0:
.../linked_list/linked_list.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void linked_list<T>::push(const T&) [with T = char]’:
.../linked_list/main.cpp:12:15:   required from here
.../linked_list/linked_list.hpp:53:40: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
   auto e = new linked_element<T*>(&elem);
                                        ^
[...]
```

Which to me doesn't make sense, if elem is of type `const T&` `&elem` should be of type `const T*` (I with debbuger and it is) and then the constructor is `new linked_element<char*>(const char*)`, hence there should be no conversion to `char*` anywhere. What am I missing? I tryed searching in google but I can't seem to get any answers (maybe I am searching for the wrong thing?).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: To answer the question in the subject line - No, the result is `char* const`, not `const char*`.

Comment: So the pointer is constant and not the value pointed to. Is there any way to end with `const char*`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124547/add-const-to-reference

Comment: Storing `&elem` is a bad idea. The reference might refer to a temporary whose lifetime will expire soon - and this is in fact the case the way you call `push('a')`.

Comment: @aschepler thanks, the code does have a lot of mistakes, didn't realize this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a `T = int`. Now I want to have a `const T`. So a constant `T`, or a `const int`.

I have a `T = char*`. Now I want to have a `const T`. So a constant `T`, so a constant `char*` so a `char *const`. It's an important distinction. The pointer itself is const, not the value pointed by it.

If you replace the `T` in `const T` with its value `char*`, then yes you get `const char*`, but that's not how the type system works :)

Similary, with `T = char&`, `const T` will be a `char&` and not a `const char&`, as there is no such case as a constant reference and so it is ignored.

Comment: Is there any way to end with `const char*`? Because AFAIK in list_element<const T*>, `const` is ignored.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer)

Comment: Using `remove_pointer<E>*` in the constructor would require me to pass a pointer to `remove_pointer` and it only removes one "pointing" layer if I have E = int** the same problem would arise. How would I use this?

Comment: @EmmanuelMess `remove_pointer` does what it advertises, it removes one pointer layer. You don't have to provide a pointer to `remove_pointer` because you're supposed to use the underlying type member called `type`. The constructor should take a `const std::remove_pointer_t<E>*`. There is no recursive remove pointer in the standard, so have a look at the answer of [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951868/recursive-stdremove-pointer).